# SQL LIKE too slow identifying potential duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to improve the quality of data in a Premises table.

Please see the DDL below (very simplified):

```
CREATE TABLE #Premises (ID int identity, Name varchar(100), primary key (ID))
INSERT INTO #Premises (name) values ('Tesco')
INSERT INTO #Premises (name) values ('Tesco Direct')
```

and the SQL below:

```
select * from #Premises inner join #Premises as Premises2
ON #Premises.Name like '%' + Premises2.Name + '%'
where #Premises.ID<>Premises2.ID
```

This returns one row because Tesco Direct is like Tesco.  However, there are millions of rows and this is obviously slow.  The database is installed on a server with SQL Enterprise edition.  Is this a scenario where full text search would help?

Comment: Yes.  `LIKE` is going to be quite slow.

Comment: Sometimes NOT using * and using specific needed columns can help performance.  Perhaps an index on the name?

Comment: Using PATINDEX may be a little faster but string operations are not the best performing operations anyway.

Comment: `Like` is slow. Even more when you write something like `... where name Like '%John'`. It is best practice not to start the literal with `%`. For full text ... I 'm not sure how to use it in that case.

Comment: IMHO before thinking about speed you need to find an algorithm that would find the correct 'dupes'. Your way of using like is not a good one. What if the first record had "TescoDirect" or "Tesco  Direct" or just "Tes" in it. Like would be quite slow and I don't think fulltext would help either (neither soundex() ... functions). Maybe you should think of some CLR function - SQL server itself is quite slow in string operations.

Comment: @Cetin Basoz, are you referring to a function like: Levenstein Distance? Would running it as a CLR function be quicker than as an SQL Server function?

Comment: The query outlined is comparing every single row in the table with all rows in the table - this is always going to be extremely slow, regardless of how they are compared. Is there no way to drastically reduce the number of rows being compared - eg. only compare rows with names shorter than 10 characters against rows with names of at least 10 characters?

Comment: Do you consider "Tesco Direct" and "XYZ  Tesco"   duplicate as well

Comment: I don't have a specific comparison in my mind. Just thinking, whatever it is, it would be very slow to do without CLR functions. I experienced SQL server string functions to be very very slow compared to CLR ones.

Comment: This is basically going to be a cartesian join evaluating billions of combinations.

Answer (score 0):

Relational databases gets it's astonishing speed grats to indexes and direct matches between keys through simple evaluation.

You are in fact trying to do a massive (and not simple) string processing in a huge mass of data. I also did sanitize data inputed by lazy humans from big databases and it's a pain.

You problem can get difficult you need to find dupes from;
"zip", "zip code", "Z.I.P.", "k9", "K-9", "Canine", "potatos", "potatoes"...

FTS can help but and it's usefullness depends on what do you want (and it's a pain to tune).

There's no easy way to sanitize your data. Just keep in mind to do it in a incremental way allowing you to it in several small steps.

One thing you can do to facilitate your workload and improve your matches is to implement a table of TAGS, a dictionary with all words in you text fields and a table to link each word to it ocurrences. That way you can analyse your possible dupes and target it.
Also creating this solution ill take time and consume your server resources to a point you ill do this job on maintenance windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any control of the data in the 2 fields you could try parsing the Name field like a delimited string.  Here is some code that you can try.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplitString] 
( 
    @string nvarchar(MAX), 
    @delimiter char(1) 
) 
RETURNS @output TABLE(splitdata nvarchar(MAX) 
) 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @start int, @end int 
    SELECT @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string) 
    WHILE @start < LEN(@string) + 1 
    BEGIN 
        IF @end = 0  
            SET @end = LEN(@string) + 1

        INSERT INTO @output (splitdata)  
        VALUES(SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start)) 
        SET @start = @end + 1 
        SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @start)

    END 
    RETURN 
END

GO

CREATE TABLE #Premises (ID int identity, Name varchar(100), primary key (ID))
INSERT INTO #Premises (name) values ('Tesco')
INSERT INTO #Premises (name) values ('Tesco Direct')

CREATE TABLE #tmp(Id int, Name varchar(100))

INSERT INTO #tmp (Id, Name)
SELECT Id, dbo.fnSplitString(Name, ' ')
FROM #Premises

CREATE INDEX idxName ON #tmp(Name)
CREATE INDEX idxId ON #tmp(Name)

SELECT * 
FROM #tmp AS Premises
    INNER JOIN #tmp AS Premises2 ON Premises.Name = Premises2.Name
WHERE Premises.ID <> Premises2.ID
```

This code will only work for matching single words.  It will not work for multiple word combinations.

Comment: Of all the string splitters this is about the worst performing version you can come up with. It would be a big help for you to check out this article for some better performing options for splitters. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings